# Why the 'Error: Couldn't find preset "react-hot" relative to directory..." in ReactJS for React Hot Loader?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, react-hot-loader

I am trying to get React Hot Reloader to work for my ReactJS project, but I am getting an error `Error: Couldn't find preset "react-hot" relative to directory...`

I did set up preset "react-hot" in `.babelrc` but what may be the issue? I have the following set up:

**In my `package.json`:**

```
{
  "name": "practicing_client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js"
  },
  "author": "John Bana",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.14.0",
    "react": "^15.3.1",
    "react-cookie": "^0.4.8",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.1",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "react-router": "^2.7.0",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-form": "^6.0.0-rc.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^3.9.3",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.3",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.15.1"
  }
}
```

**In my `webpack.config.js`**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const config = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      loader: 'babel'
    },
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!sass')
    }]
  },
 devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({ 'process.env':{ 'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production') } }),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: { warnings: false },
      output: {comments: false },
      mangle: false,
      sourcemap: false,
      minimize: true,
      mangle: { except: ['$super', '$', 'exports', 'require', '$q', '$ocLazyLoad'] }
    }),
  ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

**In my `.babelrc`:**

```
{
  "presets": ["react-hot", "react", "es2015", "stage-0"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`react-hot-loader` isn't used by Babel, it's used by Webpack.

Remove `react-hot` from your Babel presets, then add the loader to your Webpack configuration file:

```
loaders: [{
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
  loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel']
},
```

Comment: so with the new update, they recommended me to put "plugins": ["react-hot-loader/babel"] in .babelrc and no errors and all's clear. But when I test it out with a chance and save it, the browser doesn't update with the new change and doesn't log anything either. I thought I set it all up properly. What could I be missing?

Comment: Oh, yeah, I forgot that a fresh install of `react-hot-loader` will pull down the beta of v3.0.0.  Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with the API changes.  If you change the version in your `package.json` to `^1.3.0`, my advice in this answer will work.

Comment: I still can't get it to work.. could you please guide me? Thank you in advance Michael!

Comment: I made a repository that sets up a boilerplate for using React with Webpack.  If you still can't get stuff to work, take a look at it: https://github.com/Mrparkers/react-webpack-boilerplate

Comment: still are able to figure it out... please help